# Erratic scrolling and no control with logitech M325 in all programs Ubuntu 18.04 bionic

Tags: wireless, mouse, intel-graphics

I have no idea why this just started tonight, but I was playing a linux game in steam and noticed I couldn't view discussions or anything as the sidescroll bar just keeps popping up and down the page. I can't even grab it and control it. So I got out of steam and noticed same thing happening in Firefox. So I rebooted and same thing. I tried researching but most of the time I can't read entire pages as it keeps shifting me back to the top and down to the bottom. I did find this link after one person said it could be graphic drivers and am trying to update via this ppa:
https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers. But doing so in terminal, I get all updates except a message saying "holding back" on mesa-va-drivers. I have continued to sudo apt-get update & upgrade with nothing else showing as needing updating. However, my sys tray shows updates available and going into Discover they show as needing to be installed. But it never asks for my password (a recent issue so I just keep updating in terminal) so the updates hang and I have to close out of the app manager. I am very new to this and have Ubuntu 18.04 bionic with KDE Plasma. I am on a laptop with Intel i7 6th gen 8 gb ram, nVidia gtx 965m and intel 500 graphics. I am not using the touchpad and only use my mouse which has worked perfectly until tonight.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I need to provide more info, please advise.

Comment: Turn off the mouse, and turn it back on. That should probably fix it. Also make sure that you've got the latest firmware installed in the Logitech Unifying dongle. See https://community.logitech.com/s/question/0D531000058b3B7CAI/logitech-response-to-research-findings. Make sure that the dongle is plugged directly into the compter's USB port.

Comment: My husband thought it was a dying battery so I changed batteries and it still happens. I have now turned it off and back on and it is still erratically scrolling up and down; I will check the link for firmware update you gave; I searched for that previously, but couldn't find anything on logitech site. The link you provided has nothing involving my mouse. Not sure what else to try since the unifying usb has never been unplugged and my mouse has worked perfectly for over a month since I installed kubuntu. Even now as I type this, the screen moves up and down randomly.

Comment: The link that I provided is for the updated firmware for the Unifying dongle (that runs the mouse).

Comment: I only see mac & pc links even though I am in Ubuntu. Do I need to boot into Windows to do this? I have a dual boot system.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Question... does the erratic screen behavior stop if you turn off the mouse, or remove the dongle from its USB port?

Comment: i am going to assume the firmware fixed it. There was no version number given just a screen saying it was up to date. But I went back into steam game (where I first encountered it) and was able to view discussions etc with no erratic scrolling. Thanks.

Comment: Never mind. I just opened another tab and it started scrolling up and down. I am going to install a screen recorder of the issue. Can I upload that here or what is the process to be able to show you the issue? Thanks.

Comment: You can try imgur.com. You didn't answer my question about if the problem goes away if you unplug the dongle, or turn off the mouse. Does the problem occur in only one app, or more? Start new comments to me with @heynnema, or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Sorry but this page is jumping all over (at will). It doesn't always happen. But it happens in all programs when it does. I have a video of both firefox tabs and terminal freaking out (like automatically pasting previously pasted commands and keyboard input is not what I type. I tried unplugging usb and leaving it in but turning off mouse, but I couldn't get it to happen at that time; however, they can both be in use and it will not happen for awhile..then it will start again. Let me see if I can use imgur.com to upload the video and I will post here again. Thanks.

Comment: It's sounding more like a keyboard/trackpad problem. Is this a laptop or a desktop? Unplug the Logitech USB dongle, and leave it out long enough to see if the problem still exists.

Comment: I have now unplugged the usb receiver and am only using the keyboard/touchpad on my laptop. I will update you after waiting several hours to see if the issue occurs without these items in use. The video I thought I recorded did not show the stuff in konsole but it does show the issue in firefox. It doesn't start until about minute 6 so skip to there and see the cursor and the erratic scrolling for about 1 1/2 minutes. Not sure if it will help but the link is: https://imgur.com/a/M6FoPfu   Thanks.

Comment: Somehow the video didn't make it to imgur. Keep me posted.

Comment: @heynnema  I guess it has to be the mouse/dongle. I left it out all day and never had an issue. I plugged it back in a few moments ago and now it is scrolling a little bit (on another tab I was reading an article) and on this site as I type this. On the other tab, I would use my mouse scroll wheel to go back down the page and it wouldn't respond. Does that mean I just cannot use this in Ubuntu or is there a fix? Thanks.

Comment: @heynnema I don't know where my previous response to you went or your answer as all I see now is your post Please see my answer... Anyway, I did as you had suggested: turned off the mouse and left the receiver in and used my logitech wireless keyboard and laptop trackpad for hours and had no issue. So it's obviously the mouse. So I swapped it with my other logitech wireless mouse and so far no issues. I don't know why the other one works in Windows 10 but not Ubuntu but at least it's solved. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

Unplugging the Logitech Unifying receiver and turning off the mouse solves the problem.

Narrow it down by just plugging the Unifying receiver back in, but leaving the mouse TURNED OFF. That'll identify if the mouse itself is causing the problem.

**Update**:

It was the mouse, as I suspected.

Comment: I actually did that after last comment. I turned the mouse off, put receiver back in and have been using the logitech 750 keyboard and my touchpad (which I hate) and no scrolling issues. So that means it's the mouse itself. I am going to try a different logitech mouse; have one at the home pc I could swap out.  Will give it a bit and report back. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Solaar. It fixed my scrolling issue with a Logitech M720.

Comment: How do you install it?

Comment: You should be able to just use the following command on Ubuntu/Debian

`sudo apt-get install -y solaar`